# What multivariate GARCH model is this?

Tags: time-series, references, econometrics, garch

I read a paper a few years ago that specifies a multivariate GARCH model with a particular form of rolling correlations. The GARCH literature is full of abbreviations and differing terminology which is probably why I have not been able to track down this particular model.

In this model, variances are modeled separately according to the usual univariate GARCH(1,1) process: $\sigma_{i,t}^2=\omega_i+\alpha_i e_{i,t-1}^2+\beta_i \sigma_{i,t-1}^2$. $e_{i,t}$ is the residual at time $t$ for the $i$th variable/component and $\sigma_{i,t}^2$ is the associated conditional variance.

Time-varying correlations $R_t$ are modeled as $R_t=(1-\theta_1-\theta_2)\overline{R}+\theta_1\Psi+\theta_2 R_{t-1}$. $\overline{R}$ is a constant correlation matrix and $\Psi$ is the empirical correlation matrix of the residuals in the previous $k$ periods before time $t$.

What is this model called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, this looks like the time-varying correlation (TVC) / varying correlation (VC) / varying conditional correlation (VCC) GARCH model of [Tse and Tsui (2002)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/073500102288618496) as mentioned on p. 21 in [Bauwens et al. (2006)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jae.842) and on p. 10 in [Silvennoinen and Terasvirta (2009)](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/56218/1/538862637.pdf).

**References**

- Bauwens, L., Laurent, S., & Rombouts, J. V. (2006). [Multivariate GARCH models: a survey.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jae.842) *Journal of Applied Econometrics, 21*(1), 79-109.
- Silvennoinen, A., & Teräsvirta, T. (2009). [Multivariate GARCH models.](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/56218/1/538862637.pdf) In *Handbook of Financial Time Series* (pp. 201-229). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.
- Tse, Y. K., & Tsui, A. K. C. (2002). [A multivariate generalized autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity model with time-varying correlations.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/073500102288618496) *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics, 20*(3), 351-362.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This looks right so I am making as "accepted". The paper I recall was different, but there is no doubt Tse and Tsui (2002) describes this exact model. Now that I have this citation I will add a comment later if I happen to find the exact one that I was thinking of.

Comment: @RSmall, sounds good.